# Torus Maze Generator

Tags: java

I have been working on a project to randomly generate a torus made through the use of an adjacency list and disjoint set structure *(to be extended to solve the maze later)*, made from scratch. I *think* that I have optimized my code pretty well, but may have over-looked some things.

**Program Description:**

The program works by randomly picking a row and a node in that row to generate an edge for, while there are more than 1 disjoint sets remaining. Checks are done to ensure that the nodes are not already a part of the same set as well.

**Desired from post**

- Efficiency improvements
- Bugs found (if any)
- Suggestions on clarity improvements

**Constraints**

- There are no boundaries in a torus maze; *exterior* nodes will "wrap" to the opposite side of the row or column that they exist on.
- **I cannot use any pre-built Java data structures other than Arrays and Strings**
- Maze must be able to generate `(2^p)^2` elements with 'p' being in the inclusive range of 1 to 6, with random edge weights 'q' from inclusive 1 to q.

**Test Input File**

The 'M P Q' command works by passing two arguments:
*(The max I have tested this program with is: M 12 50, which creates 16,777,216 nodes)*

1. P: Defines the dimensions of the maze
2. Q: Defines the maximum weight of generated edges

> N
>   M 6 40
>   E

### Disjoint Set (Union-Find) Structure

```
/*
 * Defines the Union-Find (Disjoint set) structure, using union by size
 * and path compression. All values initialized
 */
class UnionFind {
    public int [] sets;
    public List [] g;
    public int totalPathLength;
    public int callsToFind;

    /*
     * Creates the structure and initializes all index (0 -> n-1) values
     * to -1
     */
    UnionFind (int numElements) {
        totalPathLength = 0;
        callsToFind = 0;
        sets = new int [numElements];       
        g    = new List[numElements];

        for (int i = 0; i < sets.length; i++) {
            sets [i] = -1;
            g[i] = new List();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Join two disjoint sets by size. If x and y are the same size,
     * tree containing y becomes subtree of root containing x.
     * 
     * @param   x   Attempt to find the integer in the set and union it to y
     * @param   x   Attempt to find the integer in the set and union it to x
     */
    public void union (int x, int y) {
        int root1 = find(x);
        int root2 = find(y);

        // roots cannot be a part of the same set for union
        if (root1 != root2) {
            // Make x subtree of y
            if (sets[root2] < sets[root1]) {
                sets[root2] += sets[root1];
                sets[root1] = root2;
            }
            // Make y subtree of x
            else {
                sets[root1] += sets[root2];
                sets[root2] = root1;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Search for element 'num' and returns the key in the root of tree
     * containing 'num'. Implements path compression on each find. 
     * 
     * @param num   Element to search for in the set
     * @return      Returns the root of the set that the element is a child of
     */
    public int find (int num) {
        int k = num;
        int root, next = 0;
        callsToFind++;
        totalPathLength++;

        // Find the root
        while (sets[k] >= 0) {
            k = sets[k];
            totalPathLength++;
        }
        root = k;
        k = num;

        // Path compression along the trajectory of the tree from the root
        while (sets[k] >= 0) {
            next = sets[k];
            sets[k] = root;
            k = next;
        }
        return root;
    }

    /*
     *  Displays contents of each element; Negative values represent
     *  the size of the subtree. Negative values also indicate that the
     *  element is the root for the tree
     */
    public void printAll () {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < sets.length) {
            System.out.print (sets[i] + " ");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    /**
     * @return  Returns the number of disjoint sets present in the structure
     */
    public int numberOfSets () {
        int num = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < sets.length) {
            if (sets[i] < 0) {
                num++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return num;
    }

    /*
     * Prints statistics for the structure:
     * Number of disjoint sets present in the structure
     * Also the average path length required across all calls to find
     */
    public void printStats () {
        System.out.printf ("Number of sets remaining =  %4d" ,numberOfSets());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf ("Mean path length in find =  %6.2f" , (float)totalPathLength / callsToFind);
    }
} // End UnionFind Class
```

---

### Test Client

```
/*
 * Test Client
 */
public class EVBEP3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Used for accepting command line arguments
        //Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        // Used for testing purposes
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("p3in3.txt"));
        UnionFind uf = new UnionFind (0);
        String line = "";
        boolean done = false;
        long startTime = 0;
        long endTime = 0;

        // Loop runs as long as done != true
        while (!done) {
            line = sc.nextLine();   
            String [] tokens = line.split(" "); 

            if (tokens.length >= 1) {   
                switch (tokens[0]) {

                    /*
                     *  Print name followed by newline
                     */
                    case "N": {
                            System.out.println("Evan Bechtol");
                            break;
                    }

                    /*
                     *  Create Union-Find structure with elements 0 to n-1
                     */
                    case "D": {
                        int size = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                        if (size > 0) {
                            uf = new UnionFind (size);
                        }
                            break;
                    }

                    /*
                     * Call union, output the root value and the size of resulting tree.
                     */
                    case "U": {
                        int x = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                        int y = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                        uf.union(x, y);
                        break;
                    }

                    /*
                     * Call find, output root index. Keep track of total path length
                     * require in all find operations
                     */
                    case "F": {
                        int num = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                        System.out.println (uf.find(num));
                            break;  
                    }

                    /*
                     * Output array elements in structure, space separated on one line
                     */
                    case "P": {
                        uf.printAll();
                        break;
                    }

                    /*
                     * Output statistics
                     */
                    case "S": {         
                            uf.printStats();
                            break;
                    }

                    /*
                     * Create new UnionFind class, generate torus maze and print the
                     * connections between the various nodes
                     */
                    case "M": {

                            int p = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]); // Used to define the dimensions of maze
                            int twoP = (int)(Math.pow(2, p));    // Represents 2^p
                            int d = twoP * twoP;                 // Represents total number of nodes length * width
                            int q = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]); // Represents edge weights
                            int i = 0;              // Represents 
                            int j = 0;
                            int choice = 0;
                            int numSets = d;
                            int weight = 0;
                            uf = new UnionFind (d);

                            // Union nodes together until there is only one set.
                            // This controls how the maze is constructed, ensures randomization.
                            while (numSets > 1) {
                                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                choice = randInt(0, 3);
                                weight = randInt(1, q);
                                i = randInt (0, twoP + (-1));
                                j = randInt (twoP * i , twoP * (i + 1) + (-1));

                                // If the noeds are not in the same set already, and they present a valid neighbor
                                // union is performed and number of sets is decremented.
                                if ((uf.find(i) != uf.find(j)) && uf.g[j].validEdges (i, j, twoP, choice, weight)) {
                                    uf.union(i, j);
                                    numSets += -1;
                                }
                            }

                            // i is reused as an iterator here
                            i = 0;
                            // Display the connections between nodes
                            for (List list : uf.g) {
                                System.out.println ("Node " + i);
                                //list.display();
                                list.printMaze();
                                i++;
                            }
                            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            break;
                    }

                    /*
                     *  End of data file, print newline and exit
                     */
                    case "E": {
                            System.out.println();
                            done = true;    // Break the loop, end the program
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println ("Run time for M command in milliseconds: " + (endTime - startTime));
        sc.close();
    }


    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

        // NOTE: Usually this should be a field rather than a method
        // variable so that it is not re-seeded every call.
        Random rand = new Random();

        // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
        // so add 1 to make it inclusive
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        return randomNum;
    }
} // End EVBEP3 Class
```

---

### Adjacency List Structure

```
/*
 * The Node class creates individual elements that populate the 
 * List class. Contains indexes of the node's neighbors and their
 * respective edge weights
 */
class Node {
    public int top;
    public int topWeight;
    public int bottom;
    public int bottomWeight;
    public int left;
    public int leftWeight;
    public int right;
    public int rightWeight;
    public int numConnec;

    // Default constructor, ititializes neghbors to -1 by default and edge
    // weights to 0
    Node () {
        top    = -1;
        right  = -1;
        bottom = -1;
        left   = -1;
    }
} // End Node class


/*
 * The List class contains Nodes, which are linked to one another
 * to create a Linked List. Used as an adjacency list in the
 * UnionFind class
 */
 class List {
    public Node neighbors;

    // Default constructor
    List () {
        neighbors = new Node ();
    }


    /*
     * Display all connections for the node, regardless if a connection is present
     * or not. Also displays edge weights.
     */
    public void display () {
        System.out.print("Top Neighbor   : " + neighbors.top + '\n');
        System.out.print("Top Weight     : " + neighbors.topWeight + '\n');
        System.out.print("Left Neighbor  : " + neighbors.left + '\n');
        System.out.print("Left Weight    : " + neighbors.leftWeight + '\n');
        System.out.print("Right Neighbor : " + neighbors.right + '\n');
        System.out.print("Right Weight   : " + neighbors.rightWeight + '\n');
        System.out.print("Bottom Neighbor: " + neighbors.bottom + '\n');
        System.out.print("Bottom Weight  : " + neighbors.bottomWeight + '\n' + '\n');
    }

    /**
     * Generates valid edges for the node, also assigns a randomly generated weight to that edge
     * @param i         The row that the node exists on, used to generate outer-node edges
     * @param j         The index of the node in the maze from 0 to (2^p)^2 - 1
     * @param twoP      Represents the dimensions of the maze, used in calculating valid edges
     * @param choice    Randomly generated number to choose which edge to generate
     * @param weight    Randomly generated number to assign generated edge a weight
     * @return          If the assignment was done correctly, returns true. Else returns false.
     */
    public boolean validEdges (int i, int j, int twoP, int choice, int weight) {
        if (neighbors.numConnec < 4) {
            // Top
            if (choice == 0) {
                neighbors.top = generateTop(i, j, twoP);
                neighbors.topWeight = weight;
                neighbors.numConnec++;
            }

            // Right
            else if (choice == 1) {
                neighbors.right = generateRight(i, j, twoP);
                neighbors.rightWeight = weight;
                neighbors.numConnec++;
            }

            // Bottom
            else if (choice == 2) {
                neighbors.bottom = generateBottom(i, j, twoP);
                neighbors.bottomWeight = weight;
                neighbors.numConnec++;
            }

            // Left
            else if (choice == 3) {
                neighbors.left = generateLeft(i, j, twoP);
                neighbors.leftWeight = weight;
                neighbors.numConnec++;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * Utilizes StringBuilder instance to gather the number of connections
     * to other nodes for this node, then get the nodes connected to, finally
     * getting the weights of edges in order of top -> right -> bottom -> left
     * 
     * Format is as follows:  
     * #Connections  Connected Nodes(each node displayed)  Connected Edge Weights(each node displayed)
     */
    public void printMaze () {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        // Append number of connections to str
        if (neighbors.numConnec > 0) {
            str.append(neighbors.numConnec + " ");

            // Append connections to str
            if (neighbors.top > -1) {
                str.append(neighbors.top + " ");
            }
            if (neighbors.right > -1) {
                str.append(neighbors.right + " ");
            }
            if (neighbors.bottom > -1) {
                str.append(neighbors.bottom + " ");
            }
            if (neighbors.left > -1) {
                str.append(neighbors.left + " ");
            }

            // Append weights to str
            if (neighbors.topWeight > 0) {
                str.append(neighbors.topWeight + " ");
            }
            if (neighbors.rightWeight > 0) {
                str.append(neighbors.rightWeight + " ");
            }
            if (neighbors.bottomWeight > 0) {
                str.append(neighbors.bottomWeight + " ");
            }
            if (neighbors.leftWeight > 0) {
                str.append(neighbors.leftWeight + " ");
            }
        }
        else {
            str.append("0");
        }

        System.out.println(str);
    }

    public int generateTop (int i, int j, int twoP) {
        int neighbor = 0;

        // Set the top neighbor
        if (i == 0) {
            neighbor = j + twoP * (twoP + (-1));
        }
        else {
            neighbor = j + (-twoP);
        }
        return neighbor;
    }

    public int generateRight (int i, int j, int twoP) {
        int neighbor = 0;

        // Set the right neighbor
        if (j == twoP * (i + 1) + (-1)) {
            neighbor = twoP * i;
        }
        else {
            neighbor = j + 1;
        }
        return neighbor;
    }

    public int generateBottom (int i, int j, int twoP) {
        int neighbor = 0;

        // Set the bottom neighbor
        if (i == twoP + (-1)) {
            neighbor = j - twoP * (twoP + (-1));
        }
        else {
            neighbor = j + twoP;
        }
        return neighbor;
    }

    public int generateLeft (int i, int j, int twoP) {
        int neighbor = 0;

        // Set the left neighbor
        if (j == twoP * i) {
            neighbor = twoP * (i + 1) + (-1);
        }
        else {
            neighbor = j + (-1);
        }
        return neighbor;
    }
} // End List class
```

Comment: Like the way you organized this, +1.

Comment: @Legato Thanks :) I think that clarity goes a long way for getting good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post will focus on your implementation of Union-Find.

<strike>First and foremost, you're not using the `g` member at all, so you should probably remove that.</strike> It turns out you actually are using this, just not in your Union-Find class. **This is a bad idea.** We typically wish to minimise coupling, and using a public `g` member in this manner does precisely the opposite.

Next, all your members are `public`. This usually isn't advisable; you should endeavour to make them `private` and provide getters and setters as appropriate.

Next, you are in my opinion overloading (not in the programming sense! :P) the `sets` member. It's doing double-duty, holding the nonnegative parent node index for child nodes, and the negated size of the set for root nodes. The name therefore *cannot* be meaningful, since its two purposes are so distinct.

If you are pressed for memory then I understand your use of that solution. Keep in mind, however, that since disjoint-set structures are really forests, the classic implementation uses `Node` objects containing a `parent` reference and optionally an `int` for `rank` / `size`. This has the advantage of being more semantically meaningful (and arguably more readable):

```
private class UnionFindNode {
    private UnionFindNode parent; // this, if root
    private ... data;
    private int rank; // optional
}
```

Finally, your implementation of `numberOfSets()` is linear when it could be constant. Observe that performing a union operation (on two disjoint sets) will decrease the number of disjoint sets by exactly one. Then, you could add a member (say, `numDisjointSets`) initialised to `numElements` that you decrement in your `union()` function.

---

Minor things:

- Function calls seem inconsistent — why do you use a space before the argument list sometimes, but not always? (It seems like you omit the space if it takes no arguments. If so, why do you have a space in your declarations for functions taking no arguments?)
- There seems to be an arbitrary space in `sets [i] = -1;` in your initialisation function.
- Using a `for..in` loop in `printAll()` seems more idiomatic.
- Consider renaming `numberOfSets()` so that it uses a verb. Maybe `countDisjointSets()` or `countDistinctSets()`?
- You can use the `%n` format code to print a newline instead of `println()` in `printStats()`.

Comment: Thanks for all of your feedback!   The reason that I was using "sets" was because the project spec. specifically required the implementation that way, and also required "g" to be a part of union-find structure. (Not sure why, my prof. said that we couldn't change it though).

As far as the public variables go, I'll change that. I was just being lazy and didn't want to make getters/setters :P

Comment: Also, I just changed my numberOfSets() method to reflect the changes you suggested, as well as the printStats() method. Thank you again for your time!